# JMeter Webservice request not recording

Tags: jmeter

I'm recording my web application with Jmeter but only application request are getting recorded and not Webservice calls which are called from web pages.

Comment: Your question is vague and lacking in details. Without enough information we are unable to help you. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will be able to record all the HTTP calls your browser makes to the web server including the AJAX calls (as it is also a HTTP request). If the call was made from the client machine (ie your browser/machine). But if you app server talks to another system via webservice - JMeter can not record this as it is not happening in the client machine.

Please update your question with more information If this does not answer your question.